# How to filter based on array value in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My Schema:

```
|-- Canonical_URL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Certifications: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Certification_Authority: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- End: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- License: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Start: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CompanyId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: string (nullable = true)
|-- vendorTags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- score: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- vendor: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried the below query to select nested fields from `vendorTags`

```
df3 = sqlContext.sql("select vendorTags.vendor from globalcontacts")
```

How can I query the nested fields in `where` clause like below in PySpark

```
df3 = sqlContext.sql("select vendorTags.vendor from globalcontacts where vendorTags.vendor = 'alpha'")
```

or

```
df3 = sqlContext.sql("select vendorTags.vendor from globalcontacts where vendorTags.score > 123.123456")
```

something like this..

I tried the above queries only to get the below error

```
df3 = sqlContext.sql("select vendorTags.vendor from globalcontacts where vendorTags.vendor = 'alpha'")
```

```
16/03/15 13:16:02 INFO ParseDriver: Parsing command: select vendorTags.vendor from globalcontacts where vendorTags.vendor = 'alpha'
16/03/15 13:16:03 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 583, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._ssql_ctx.sql(sqlQuery), self)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 51, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '(vendorTags.vendor = cast(alpha as double))' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(vendorTags.vendor = cast(alpha as double))' (array<string> and double).; line 1 pos 71"
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For equality based queries you can use `array_contains`:

```
df = sc.parallelize([(1, [1, 2, 3]), (2, [4, 5, 6])]).toDF(["k", "v"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

# With SQL
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df WHERE array_contains(v, 1)")

# With DSL
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_contains
df.where(array_contains("v", 1))
```

If you want to use more complex predicates you'll have to either `explode` or use an UDF, for example something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf 

def exists(f):
    return udf(lambda xs: any(f(x) for x in xs), BooleanType())

df.where(exists(lambda x: x > 3)("v"))
```

In Spark 2.4. or later it is also possible to use higher order functions

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.where(expr("""aggregate(
    transform(v, x -> x > 3),
    false, 
    (x, y) -> x or y
)"""))
```

or

```
df.where(expr("""
    exists(v, x -> x > 3)
"""))
```

Python wrappers should be available in 3.1 ([SPARK-30681](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30681)).

Answer (score 8):

In spark 2.4 you can filter array values using filter function in sql API.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#filter

Here's example in pyspark. In the example we filter out all array values which are empty strings:

```
df = df.withColumn("ArrayColumn", expr("filter(ArrayColumn, x -> x != '')"))
```