# pyspark; check if an element is in collect_list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a dataframe `df`, for instance the following dataframe:

```
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+------+
|keys|values|
+----+------+
|  aa| apple|
|  bb|orange|
|  bb|  desk|
|  bb|orange|
|  bb|  desk|
|  aa|   pen|
|  bb|pencil|
|  aa| chair|
+----+------+
```

I use `collect_set` to aggregate and get a *set of objects with duplicate elements eliminated* (or `collect_list` to get list of objects).

```
df_new = df.groupby('keys').agg(collect_set(df.values).alias('collectedSet_values'))
```

The resulting dataframe is then as follows:

```
df_new.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----------------------+
|keys|collectedSet_values   |
+----+----------------------+
|bb  |[orange, pencil, desk]|
|aa  |[apple, pen, chair]   |
+----+----------------------+
```

I am struggling to find a way to see if a specific keyword (like 'chair') is in the resulting set of objects (in column `collectedSet_values`). I do not want to go with `udf` solution.

Please comment your solutions/ideas.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Sharing information is always a good idea, so thanks for sharing :) However, could you please reformat so it is in the Q&A format? So make sure your question only contains the actual question, and add your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Florian 
sure, i'll fix that :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually there is a nice function `array_contains` which does that for us. The way we use it for *set of objects* is the same as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014082/how-to-filter-based-on-array-value-in-pyspark). To know if word 'chair' exists in each set of object, we can simply do the following:

```python
df_new.withColumn('contains_chair', array_contains(df_new.collectedSet_values, 'chair')).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----------------------+--------------+
|keys|collectedSet_values   |contains_chair|
+----+----------------------+--------------+
|bb  |[orange, pencil, desk]|false         |
|aa  |[apple, pen, chair]   |true          |
+----+----------------------+--------------+
```

The same applies to the result of `collect_list`.