# Pyspark: Match values in one column against a list in same row in another column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe containing following 2 columns, amongst others:
1. ID
2. list_IDs

I am trying to create a 3rd column returning a boolean True or False if the ID is present in the list_ID column in the same row

I have tried using the following:

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, [1, 2, 3,]), (2, [1, 3, 4])], ("ID", "list_IDs"))

df.withColumn("IDmatch", when(col("ID").isin(F.col("list_IDs")), True).otherwise(False)).show()
```

That doesn't work. However, If I were to provide some static list to match against, it works of course.

```py
df.withColumn("IDmatch", when(col("ID").isin([2, 3]), True).otherwise(False)).show()
```

I can use a udf to return a boolean type and that works as well:

```py
@udf(returnType=BooleanType())
def isinlist(x, y):
    return x in y
```

However, I am trying to avoid using UDF in this case, if possible and I was wondering if it's possible to use something native akin to .isin() to check if the ID in a row is present in the list of values in the list_ID column for the same row?

Comment: May be something below like will work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499460/pyspark-check-if-an-element-is-in-collect-list

Comment: @vikrantrana : Thanks but if I understand correctly `array_contains` is similar to matching against a static list I described above: `df.withColumn("IDmatch", when(col("ID").isin([2, 3]), True).otherwise(False)).show()` as in it doesn't allow for matching whatever value happens to be in that row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method 1:**

If you are on Spark >= 2.4.0. You can use the inbuilt `arrays_overlap` function. This function takes in 2 arrays and checks for the common elements amongst them.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import arrays_overlap, array

df.withColumn("IDmatch", arrays_overlap(df.list_IDs, array(df.ID))).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---------+-------+
| ID| list_IDs|IDmatch|
+---+---------+-------+
|  1|[1, 2, 3]|   true|
|  2|[1, 3, 4]|  false|
+---+---------+-------+
```

You can read more about it here, https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_overlap

**Method 2:**

Alternatively, you can also use an `udf` to obtain the same output

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

element_check = udf(lambda elt_list, elt: elt in elt_list)

df.withColumn("IDmatch", element_check(df.list_IDs, df.ID)).show()
```

Comment: Wonderful!, That's insightful @noufel13. That works. Thanks.

Comment: @noufuel13 , If we have Null value at list_IDs column then how to tackle this situation.
As i am doing left join on two sparkdataframe
ID List_IDs
1 [1, 2, 3]
2 [1, 3, 4]
3

Comment: ID| list_IDs|IDmatch|
+---+---------+-------+
|  1|[1, 2, 3]|   true|
|  2|[1, 3, 4]|  false|
|  2|            |  false|

Answer (score 4):

You should define a custom `udf` that takes 2 arguments

```
val isInList = spark.udf
.register("isInList", (id: Int, ids: Seq[Int]) => ids.contains(id))
```

Output:

```
df.withColumn("IDmatch", isInList($"ID", $"list_IDs")).show()
+---+---------+-------+
| ID| list_IDs|IDmatch|
+---+---------+-------+
|  1|[1, 2, 3]|   true|
|  2|[1, 3, 4]|  false|
+---+---------+-------+
```

I am using `Scala` syntax, but the general direction should be clear.

Comment: Thanks @Gelerion. Much appreciated. I was trying to avoid having to use UDFs as much as possible and was wondering if there's a way to achieve this natively.

Comment: You could do it natively by extending  `Expression` class. It's a bit more complicated. If there won't be a solution without `udf`, I will provide an example.