# Filter a Dense vector in PySpark

Tags: vector, pyspark

Imagine we have a vector in Pyspark and we want to filter by the values that are greater than another. For example we have

m = DenseVector([1,2,3,4,5]).

Imagine we want the values that are greater than 3, in python it woulb be m[m>3].

How it is in pyspark (without using toArray()) ?

Comment: Hello and welcome. 
Are you specifically asking about a DenseVector or about a dataframe of vectors? in other words - what is the input format? Also, what is the scale of the problem?

Comment: I am specifically talking a DenseVector

Comment: umm not sure but convert it to `array`type and then try something with `F.contains`. have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014082/how-to-filter-based-on-array-value-in-pyspark)